# Sync emails over imap with a local database

Tags: php, imap, synchronization

For an email history in a php erp system i would like to sync emails with imap with a local mysql database.

It's faster than i thought to download all messages with attachments (about 5 minutes for 6000 messages), but after downloading all messages it would be great to only download the changes. The problem is that i can't rely on the date of the email because the flaggs (seen, flagged, answered, deleted) can change over time.

Is there a possibility to get only the changed emails, what is the best practice for local email clients like thunderbird?

As far as I understand the [protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-5.2), there is a server "push" method, but the php script should not be connected all the time, just as a local email client.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7766062/1100089) was quite useful, so I have to download the headers (without the body) and compare all messages in every request?

**Edit**

I know that such tools like [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/) already exists, but I would like to do it without external dependencies.

Comment: Each email has a unique ID. Use that as as index to test for existence.

Comment: Yes, in the first run i save all headers with the body (without attachments) in the database, also the uid. But how can i check BEFORE downloading all messages again which email changed and sync the changes?

Comment: Have you looked at the `SEEN` header. You can set this flag for each message as you receive each message

Comment: But the seen header is only a boolean and I don't know if the email has changed later, for example someone replied to this mail.

Comment: Messages are immutable *Except* for FLAGS.  You can assume any UID does not change, only resync the FLAGS when you connect.  Download a list of UIDs and FLAGs when you start (if you care about the flags).  Compare to the UIDs you have.  Tada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the purpose is to download all mails from imap server and then periodically check if there is any new email, which was not previously downloaded and saved to db, then I would recommend using PEAR Net_IMAP class.

PHP native IMAP has not the capability to set/get custom flags but with Net_IMAP class you can do as follows.

1. Connect to IMAP server
2. Read message.
3. Save to DB.
4. Using Net_IMAP method setFlags, set a custom flag on that message on server. for example

   ```
   setFlags('savedToDb')
   ```

Thats it.
Next iterations
connect to IMAP and check all those messages which do not have the flag that you have set.
This way you will be able to handle all emails successfully synched between your IMAP and db.

Comment: But if another flag changes, the problem still persists. I would like to be able to sync the flags, too.

Comment: As I am not aware of the full context of the application, but I assume that what you are trying to achieve is to have two identical mail apps. The solution provided above was based on the assumption that you are doing it one way. You fetch emails from server, you keep the server copy for sometime and then delete it to reclaim space. However same solution can be used to check all flags as well, and you can see if your custom flag exist, then only get flags, and update your local db but if it doesn't then get full email.

Comment: Sry I thought i mentioned it somewhere. Nevertheless this is a great solution, the flags are not that important.

Comment: is setting costom flags widely supported by most mail servers?