# Best practice updating IMAP client about deleted messages / set flags

Tags: imap

I understand how to fetch email from an IMAP server efficiently through the concept of UID and UidValidity, which is saving the last fetched UID in the IMAP client and then fetching only UIDs higher than the last fetched one, as long as the UidValidity parameter of the mailbox stays the same. (If the UidValidity changed, fetch the whole mailbox again.)

Anyway, what would be the best practice for an IMAP client to realize that messages had been deleted or flagged in the mailbox on the server (e.g. from another client)?

I found this question:
[IMAP Client Sync local messages Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758925/imap-client-sync-local-messages-server)
But I still don't know what that means? Should I again fetch all UIDs each time the IMAP client connects to the IMAP server? Does the IMAP protocol support a hash table as suggested by the selected answer?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, detecting deleted messages is one of the places that the original IMAP protocol really falls short.

Detecting messages marked `\Deleted` is pretty easy.  You can do a `UID SEARCH DELETED`, and it’ll give you the UID of all messages that are deleted.  Under the assumption that you don’t keep `\Deleted` messages around much and the mailbox is not too big, this is a reasonably efficient query.

Detecting messages that have disappeared is a bit harder.  Without the `QRESYNC` extension (which is rarely implemented), the easiest way is just to ask the server for the UIDs of all messages still present `UID SEARCH ALL`, and compare this list to the list of messages you know about.  The answer is just suggesting that locally, you may want to use some intelligent data structure to do this.  For example, in Python, you could use a `set`.  The set of messages you have, minus the set of messages the server, leaves you with a set of messages that have been removed from the server.  The set of messages the server has minus the set of messages you have, leaves you with a set of new messages.

If you only have a small number of messages on the server (< 1000) this is a reasonably efficient query too.  However, if the server has tens of thousands of messages, this can sometimes take a very long time.  IMAP doesn’t scale that well.